# Is a good practice to copy an answer from a question to a new answer?

Tags: support, questions, rejected-edits

The OP was trying to put his answer in a question, but this was rejected as radical change. Should I copy this answer from the question and place it as a new answer?

Without copying this information it is simply rejected and lost.

<del>Sample copied answer: [How to build Adhoc build to test PNS on production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898948/how-to-build-adhoc-build-to-test-pns-on-production-mode/21072904#21072904)</del>

Comment: How was the edit rejected? If the editor was the OP it shouldn't have been reviewed at all?

Comment: I reviewed this question, OP was trying to include this into question post and this was rejected. Because I have seen this edit, I copied it and putted as answer below.

Comment: Looking at the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3787897) wasn't actually the OP making the suggested edit. It was William Hu

Comment: Ups, I see. Then this is wrong example :)

Comment: Doesn't really effect the question,  I have seen OPs doing this (and done what doctoro suggested). It just struck me as odd because the OP never has to have their edits approved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best practice is for the user to actually create an answer, rather than editing the question itself.

However, there's nothing that prevents you from taking the user's answer as your own, even if at first it isn't straightforward ethic.

I would comment to the user to make him aware of the proper way to do this sort of stuff. If he doesn't care, or if he insists in changing the body of the question, you can copy the OP's answer. If it still bugs you, make your answer a CW post, as not to gain reputation from something you didn't do.

What matters here most of all is knowledge. Just that.

Answer (score 2):

The question's place is meant for question only. OP should not add his or her answer there just to tell that this question is solved!

Instead, he/she should ask question and wait for what other user's can provide him with. Then if he donot get enough attention then he should provide some bounty to attract other users to the question. If he gets an answer now, Good!

If he doesn't get answer and fixes the thing himself. Then he has the option to answer his own question and so he should. He should just answer his question and mark it as answer.

This way it would be better for the new readers about what the condition is. They would

1. Read the question and the problem. If that matches their problem then go a few scrolls below and
2. Read the answer that solved the problem.

Easy and simple isn't it? Why does he need to edit the question and include the answer there?

I think it is fair to just ask a question, and if there is a need to answer, then he should just write it at the appropriate place.

And what you did is fair. You just placed it to the place where it belongs to, you should include OP's name and condition of the post alongwith the answer.

Stack Overflow asks users to not COPY PASTE text but to write their own answer. So if you wanted to answer it as a full-credit-to-yourself then you must have written the text in your own words atleast. But hey, your post is OK!

Answer (score -1):

I would say that since you have the rep, you could put it in the question marked as an edit at the bottom, something like:

> EDIT, here's how I solved this problem:
>
> ...blah, blah, blah...

It would have been fine for him to self-answer, but the OP can show how he got things to work in the question also (though your example works better as an answer).

Comment: Real example added.

Comment: That definitely makes for a good answer, he should have just done that.

Comment: He should, but he didnt.